# How to check if a certain type of file exists with batch file?

Tags: batch-file, tensorboard

I'm studying TensorFlow now, and often write event files like`events.out.tfevents.%some number%.%PC name%`.

I want to write a batch file to check if there exists one or more event files. 
(1)If such files exist, then let user decide whether to overwrite previous files
(2)If not, run the python script to generate a new event file, then activate TensorBoard.

Suppose I have defined a user variable `%TF_DIR%`

With that in mind, I write something like:

```
set pyName=%1
cd %TF_DIR%/graphs/%pyName%
if exist *.tfevents.* 
(
    # ask if user want to overwrite, then decided whether to run the script again
)
else
( 
    echo No previous event files detected, run the script to create a new event...
    python %tfDIR%/%pyName%.py
)

tensorboard --logdir=%cd%
cd %TF_DIR%
```

Strangely the file is not working and returns something like **"invalid command syntax"** at the `if exist if exist *.tfevents.*`. I cannot find what goes wrong. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Syntax is messy: the `(` has to be on the same physical line as `if`. Same with `else`: `) else (` has to be on the same line

Comment: But I want to execute multiple statements inside `if`, including setting a new variable for user input, and another `if-else` inside the first `if` etc. It seems impossible to cram so many things inside one line... I wonder if there's an alternative way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: it's just the `(` (Beginning of code block) and `else` after `)` (End of code block), which has to be on a special position. Inside the code block you can of course use several lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax *is* incorrect; in the construction `if ... ( ... ) else ( ... )` the `(` must be of the same line as `if`, and `) else (` must be on the same line.

As a supplementary note, unless you have something against labels and `goto`, I would suggest using them instead of fancy modern tricks like `if ... ( ... ) else ( ... )`. The syntax inside `(` `)` is not necessarily what you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I think I'll write a Python script instead to handle complex condition switches in a more structural manner:)